# Find if a geometric point is within one of several polygons

Tags: node.js, mongoose, leaflet

I'm trying to find if a geometric point is within one of several polygons, i'm working wiht mongoose and node js. I found in Mongoose documentation this code.

```
    var polyA = [[[ 10, 20 ], [ 10, 40 ], [ 30, 40 ], [ 30, 20 ]]]
query.where('loc').within().geometry({ type: 'Polygon', coordinates: polyA })

// or
var polyB = [[ 0, 0 ], [ 1, 1 ]]
query.where('loc').within().geometry({ type: 'LineString', coordinates: polyB })

// or
var polyC = [ 0, 0 ]
query.where('loc').within().geometry({ type: 'Point', coordinates: polyC })

// or
query.where('loc').intersects().geometry({ type: 'Point', coordinates: polyC })
```

But all of them are for search in one polygone, i want to search in for example 10 polygons. Is that possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query if the point `intersects` or is `within` a [MultiPolygon](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/geojson/#multipolygon):

```js
var polygons = [polyA, polyB, polyC];
var multipolygon = { type: 'MultiPolygon', coordinates: polygons };
var results = query.where('loc').within().geometry(multipolygon);
```

Now, if you want to find which polygon contains the point, use [JSTS](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts):

```js
// MongoDB query result
var point = results[0].loc;

// Convert geometries to JSTS
var geojsonReader = new jsts.io.GeoJSONReader();
jstsPoint = geojsonReader.read(point);
var jstsPolygons = polygons.map(function(polygon, index) {
  jstsPolygon = geojsonReader.read({type: 'Polygon', coordinates: polygon});
  jstsPolygon.__index = index; // or use whatever suits you best
  return jstsPolygon;
});

// Find polygons containing point
jstsPolygons.filter(function(jstsPolygon){
  return jstsPoint.within(jstsPolygon);
}).forEach(function(poly) {
  console.log('Point is within polygon ' + poly.__index);
});
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/mojoqi/9/edit?js,console) is a working example of JSTS using GeoJSON geometries.

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, but i don't have a multipolygon, i have diferent polygons. It will work with that? What I'm looking for is to find in with of he polygons is within the point. Thanks again.

Comment: The code above shows how to build a multipolygon using different polygons (polyA, polyB and polyC, as in your example) and how to determine if a point is within one of them, as you asked in your question..

Comment: This example uses JSTS, but it's the same logic: http://jsbin.com/mojoqi/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Thanks again @Ricardo Stuven, my problem was that I was using a wrong MultiPolygon, now using that query, can I show in which polygon is within the point??

Comment: That's a different question :)

Once the query found what point is in the multipolygon (this is fast because of the spatial index), then you can use a library like JSTS (see code example in previous comment) and find which polygon contains the point.